# Update within mysql query results

Tags: php, mysql

hoping you can help with what I expected to be a simple function.

I'd like to allow users to remove (i.e. change published=y to published=n) a query result but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. Here's the query as is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussion WHERE publish='y' ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo ("<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "<span class=\"remove\">(<a href=\"#\">REMOVE</a>)</span></td>
    <td width=\"300\">" . nl2br($row['question']) . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['author'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</td>
    <td><a href=\"discussion.php?discussionID=" . $row['discussionID'] . "\">View Discussion</a></td></tr>");
}
```

The query I'd like to run when the user clicked 'REMOVE' (within the above query):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE discussion SET publish='n' WHERE discussionID='XXXXX");
```

Any ideas from the fine people at SO?

New to php/mysql so forgive the ignorance.

Comment: just make it usual way - forms, buttons and action script to perform actual delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest option here would be to insert your remove button into a form.

Try adding this form into your table. I am echoing the discussionID into the checkbox so that you can distinguish between the multiple checkboxes in the table:

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <input type="checkbox" id="removeCheckbox" name="removeCheckbox" value="<?php echo $row['discussionID']; ?>" />
     <input id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then in your PHP, you update the database with the value of the checkbox:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['removeCheckbox'])) {
    $checkboxValue = $_POST['removeCheckbox'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE discussion SET publish='y' WHERE discussionID='$checkboxValue'");
}

?>
```

Does that make sense?

**EDIT:** This should now work! Also updated to include Dan's suggestion.

Comment: Not much. Value should contain actual id, not just "y"

Comment: Col, the updated answer should now work. I misread the question and didn't realize there were going to be multiple checkboxes.

Comment: You should use `if (isset($_POST['removeCheckbox']))`. If the box is not checked, then that key won't even exist in the post data, so trying to compare it to the empty string will generate a notice.

Comment: Checkboxes supposed to process multiple rows at once. Either add array processing to the code or make it just a button without checkbox. and it's always need to mention intval()/mysql_real_escape_string(). Never suppose the op already doing it. They don't.

Comment: I did my best, Col. 

@rrfive, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Col, works like a charm! I was hoping there was some fancy way to avoid the use of checkboxes but it is what it is. Thanks very much for the help. Only one issue left. I've added a header "(header("Location: discussion_index.php");)" to refresh the page but alas, it's not working (added just below the mysql_query line). The update works, the header does not. Any ideas?

Comment: @rrfive, you're welcome. Why do you need to refresh the page with a header after the update? When you click the submit button, it should refresh the page. Just make sure you put the update statement above the form, and you should be good. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @epaps, turns out I was being a jackass. After a little sleep, some food and a new day I was able to use my brain and sort it. Thanks again for the help. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

the same way you do a link to go to the discussion ( a href=\"discussion.php?discussionID=" . $row['discussionID'] . "\">View Discussion ).

a href=\"delete_discussion.php?discussionID=" . $row[ 'discussionID' ] . "\">REMOVE
and create the delete_discussion.php file to run your update query

Comment: Not exactly the same, because it should be POST form button, not GET hyperlink